# Unity 5.2 convert fixed function to shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I use a plugin (VTP2.0, now unsupported) in Unity3D for playing video. The new Unity 5.2 changes break the fixed function shader that it uses:

```
safeMaterial = new Material (
    "Shader \"Hidden/Invert\" {" +
    "SubShader {" +
    " Pass {" +
    " ZTest Always Cull Off ZWrite Off" +
    " SetTexture [_RenderTex] { combine texture }" +
    " }" +
    "}" +
    "}"
    );
```

How can I convert this to a shader so it can be used in the new Unity?

What I tried:

```
safeMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Hidden/Invert"));
```

With the shader:

```
Shader "Hidden/Invert" {
SubShader {
    Pass {
        ZTest Always Cull Off ZWrite Off
        SetTexture [_RenderTex] {
            combine texture
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

I think I'm missing something though, as it still doesn't work.